# CPU overheating, the fan won't speed up, but it's not the fan

Tags: cpu, fan, overheating

I have 2 identical PCs, with the only difference being the GPU. One of the CPUs is overheating without the fan going up in speed, but if I gently press the fan manually, it speeds up as it seems to detect the temperature, but otherwise it doesn't go much over 2700 RPM, and the usual temperature of the CPUs is 60, while the other is 30.

The thing is, it's not the fan, it's actually the CPU. I only switched the CPUs between the two PCs and now the second PC is the one overheating. The problem started long before I switched the CPUs, so I ruled out some pin bending, and since the fans didn't switch with the CPUs, it also can't be the fans.

Before going any further, yes, I did the basics: clean the fans, change the thermal paste, etc.

So the question is, is there anything else I can do to trace the problem, before I admit to myself that the CPU is busted?

Comment: the temperature sensor on the die is probably bad.  is it under warranty?  something like that should be covered.  as a workaround you can use a third party utility to run the cpu fan at a higher rate all the time.  just gotta keep an eye on the temps so you dont burn it out.

Comment: Should have mentioned, but I already use SpeedFan, and got the fan to go to around 3300 RPM, but it doesn't seem to go any faster by itself. It only goes to 600+ RPM only if I press the fan. The CPU is around 3 years old, so the warranty is already over. I'll try to find some tool that will show mb and cpu sensors. The temperature I get from SpeedFan is high, so it can't be the cpu sensor. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you may want to check that dynamic frequency / speedstep is set up, that can help to keep the temps down.  also you may be able to set the fan speed in your bios.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem a while ago. My Acer Aspire 5542G notebook was overheating and the fan just wasn't spinning fast enough to cool down the CPU.

SpeedFan didn't allow me to control my fan speeds so I set out to look for other options and came across [RWEverything](http://rweverything.com/), which is a **very** powerful tool that lets you tinker with your motherboard's Embedded Controller (EC) among other things.

Read [this informative forum post](http://forum.notebookreview.com/acer/562576-acer-aspire-timelinex-3820tg-mods-tweaks-only.html) on how to use RWEverything to tinker with the EC to manually control your fan speeds. Be well aware that a wrong move could bring your system crashing down or worse, cause physical damage to computer components.

[This post](http://forum.notebookreview.com/acer/652553-trying-lower-fan-speed-acer-aspire-5536g.html) also helped me while I was looking for the correct offsets for fan speed control in the EC RAM.

Changes made to the EC are reset after a reboot, so you might want to make a batch script and run it at boot to set the fan speed correctly. Here's [what I used](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1ronryfi1s87y7f/dZ97najjBp/Acer%20Aspire%205542G%20-%20Fan%20Speed%20Control#/) for my computer.

The fan speed control offsets in the EC RAM are different for every computer model so you might have to experiment a little to find yours. However, do not attempt to make any changes to the EC RAM unless you fully understand what you're doing and the implications of your actions.

Answer (score 0):

as it seems the temp sensor 'on-die' got busted, by now you can download a cpu temp monitor like [Core Temp](http://alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) (there's a free version), this one comes with a utility that can set up the RPM speed of the cpu heatsink fan depending on user-defined temp parameters, so you can customize the fan speed

but is better to start saving money and buy a new cpu

Comment: I'll give that one a try. I'm using SpeedFan, and it shows a high temperature, so if what you're saying is correct, there should be 2 sensors: one in the mb, and another in the cpu, and SpeedFan is only showing the mb sensor. I'll see what I can find about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be a bad application of the thermal paste between the CPU and the heatsink. Air acts as an insulator and not as a conductor in this case so any "bubbles" would cause heat to not dissipate effectively. It's a fairly cheap thing to try in addition to possibly looking at a new fan+heatsink which could help as well.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem... The fast heat sink fan with high rpm and hot cpu above 56°C. Once after i changed the processor, it was fine