# Controlling fan speed with Windows

Tags: windows, fan

I have an Asrock mainboard with terrible software to control the fan speed: it doesn't start automatically and it doesn't run for all users. So I'm looking for Software to control the fan speed. It should start when Windows (7) starts and should run independent of the user.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) by Almico. It does the job of both monitoring the Fan Speed/CPU Temp/Hard Disks etc... and also control the speed of fans. You can also configure it to run during windows start up so that you don't have to manually start it each time.

Answer (score 2):

I had an Acer notebook that wouldn't work with SpeedFan or any other fan speed control software.

I finally used [RWEverything](http://rweverything.com/) to change values at certain offsets of the notebook's embedded controller memory to set fan speed to 100%

This is quite risky if you don't know exactly what you're doing and you may end up crashing your PC or worse, cause physical damage to internal components.

Here's [my answer to a similar question](https://superuser.com/a/733290/167187). Refer to that for instructions.

Once you've found the correct offsets that control fan speed, you might want to edit the batch scripts from [my solution for Acer 5542G notebooks](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1ronryfi1s87y7f/dZ97najjBp/Acer%20Aspire%205542G%20-%20Fan%20Speed%20Control#/) and [add it to the startup folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1154701/1768141)

Comment: That has been taken a step further (aka easier for the average layman) with [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc).

Answer (score -1):

[SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) monitors hardware and can read values such as temperatures, fan speeds, voltages, etc.

> SpeedFan monitor temperatures from several sources. By properly configuring SpeedFan, you can let it change fan speeds based on system temperatures. When choosing parameters for the minimum and maximum fan speed, try to set them by hand (disable all the VARIATE FANs checkboxes) and listen to the noise. When you hear no noise from the fan then you can set that value as the minimum fan speed for that fan. I suggest to use 100 as the maximum value, unless you hear a lot of noise from it, in which case you might reduce the maximum speed to 95 or 90.

It is added to the startup programs group and will run for all users.