# Tune Fan Speeds On Old Motherboards?

Tags: motherboard, fan, cool-n-quiet

I just found out that you can easily tune your fan speed by using (an up-to-date) motherboard utility like Asus AI Suite 3 to make your pc quieter. Unfortunately, I can't install it probably because my motherboard is too old to be supported:

[image]

At least Asus AI Suite II works:

[image]

Unfortunately, I does not seem to be possible to tune fan speed with Asus AI Suit II :(
**Is there another way to do so for my (old) motherboard?**

---

### Edit

I tried SpeedFan, however, it shows me that my CPU temp is too hot, even though I am sure the important temperature that matters is the CPU core temperature, which is alright. When I turn "Automatic fan speed" on, nothing happens, probably because of Temp1 (CPU Temp)?

[image]

Comment: I can't provide pics/refs but you used to do it from the BIOS. Fans could be set to some terms like active, normal or quiet.

Comment: Aerocool still sells some [fan control panels](https://aerocool.io/accessories/) for their cases, could be a good idea if your case has a free space in the front panel

Comment: There are 3rd party utilities for fan speed management, many of which thar have been around a long time and support a wide range of hardware.

Comment: [Controlling fan speed with Windows - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/799028/controlling-fan-speed-with-windows/799037#799037)

Comment: I added my SpeedFan experience to the description

Comment: I don’t think 3rd party fan speed software works on old motherboard. I have tried. We can monitor but can not control it. Speedfan also does not work. What you can change is adjust the fan speed threshold from BIOS screen. If you change the threshold to a higher value, you can get a quieter fan but the increase in temperature might damage pc parts. I had experience damaging my passively cooled Graphics card.